# My Backbone view got very big almost 1k lines and 30 events

Tags: backbone.js

My view got very big almost 1k lines and 30 events.Should I brake it in smaller sub views?
I want to do this to improve readability and performance.

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should brake it in smaller sub views. Although it will not necessary improve performance but will definitely improve readability. Also please keep in mind that views are only for presentation and not business logic.